# How do I reference a whole GitHub project using Paket?

Tags: f#, paket

According to [the docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/github-dependencies.html#Referencing-a-GitHub-repository) I can fetch a whole GitHub repository with a line like this in my `paket.dependencies`:

```
// master branch
github tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting

// version 2.13.5
github tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting:2.13.5

// specific commit 30cd5366a4f3f25a443ca4cd62cd592fd16ac69
github tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting:30cd5366a4f3f25a443ca4cd62cd592fd16ac69
```

But what should I put in my `paket.refrences` in order to reference the dependency?

Comment: Have you tried adding `tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting`?

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox that makes Paket assume a Nuget package.

Comment: Have you tried adding a project reference in the normal way, referencing the downloaded project in your `paket-files` directory?